# Is it a bug for pushViewController

Tags: ios, iphone

I used the code below to present vViewController1

```
  @property (retain,nonatomic) ViewController1 *vViewController1;
```

...

push vViewController1 from rootViewController

```
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vViewController1 animated:NO];
```

Viewcontroller1's viewWillAppear

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480);

    self.view.frame = frame; ///aaa

    NSLog(@"%f:%f:%f:%f",
   frame.origin.x,frame.origin.y,frame.size.width,frame.size.height);



}
```

it outputs

```
0.000000:20.000000:320.000000:480.000000
```

but the view y position is always at

```
0
```

rather than

```
20
```

it looks like it is always

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
```

and

```
 self.view.frame = frame; ///aaa
```

can not relocate the position of the view.

I have try to set the position using code when call pushViewController,

but there is no way to make it work correctly.

Just wonder if it is a bug for pushViewController

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have autolayout turned on. So you need to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
}
```

And it's better to use `NSStringFromCGRect` for NSLog, rather creating 4 outputs doubles.

Comment: thanks aaaaaaaaaaaaa lot, my friend. It looks like this is the only way does work !!!